# Extract first and last name from an email address when separated by both a "." or an "_"

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to extract a first name and last name from an email address but also need to make the case proper with capital letters for first and last name.
I know this is pretty easy to do, but what I keep running into is that there is no solution that provides removing both a `.` and a `_`.

I've tried to use:

```
=ArrayFormula(PROPER(substitute(regexextract($E3:$E,"(.*)@"), ".", " ")))
```

and yes, this extracts it, makes it proper case and removes the `.` from the name, but fails when it encounters an email like `first_last`.
I'm not much of a pro Sheets user so if anyone has any insight that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula instead

```
=INDEX(PROPER(REGEXREPLACE
        (REGEXEXTRACT($E3:$E,"(.*)@"), "\.|_", " ")))
```